# jq preserving array boundaries

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I've got an API that reports group membership as an array where each group is an array element that has an array of members.  I want to simplify the data, but not remove the array boundaries.

When there are three groups the API produces this output, call it '3gr.json' :

```
[
   {
      "id" : "000E58D2E9B401400",
      "members" : [
         {
            "id" : "000E58D2E9B401400",
            "roomName" : "Room1",
            "groupState" : {
               "mute" : false,
               "volume" : 15
            },
            "state" : {
               "playbackState" : "STOPPED",
               "volume" : 15,
               "mute" : false
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id" : "000E58D2FA0601400",
      "members" : [
         {
            "state" : {
               "playbackState" : "STOPPED",
               "volume" : 40,
               "mute" : false
            },
            "id" : "000E58D2FA0601400",
            "roomName" : "Room2",
            "groupState" : {
               "mute" : false,
               "volume" : 40
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id" : "5CAAFD7B8C9801400",
      "members" : [
         {
            "groupState" : {
               "mute" : false,
               "volume" : 15
            },
            "roomName" : "Room3",
            "id" : "5CAAFD7B8C9801400",
            "state" : {
               "mute" : false,
               "playbackState" : "STOPPED",
               "volume" : 15
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

When there is one group the the API produces this output, call it '1gr.json' :

```
[
  {
    "id": "000E58D2E9B401400",
    "members": [
      {
        "id": "000E58D2E9B401400",
        "state": {
          "volume": 44,
          "mute": false,
          "playbackState": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
          "equalizer": {
            "bass": 2,
            "treble": 2,
            "loudness": true
          }
        },
        "roomName": "Room1",
        "groupState": {
          "volume": 46,
          "mute": false
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "5CAAFDE9614001400",
        "state": {
          "volume": 54,
          "mute": false,
          "playbackState": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
          "equalizer": {
            "bass": 0,
            "treble": 0,
            "loudness": true
          }
        },
        "roomName": "Room2",
        "groupState": {
          "volume": 65,
          "mute": false
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "5CAAFD7B8C9801400",
        "state": {
          "volume": 41,
          "mute": false,
          "playbackState": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
          "equalizer": {
            "bass": 0,
            "treble": 0,
            "loudness": false
          }
        },
        "roomName": "Room3",
        "groupState": {
          "volume": 41,
          "mute": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I use `jq` to process this output:

```
jq '.[].members[]|{name: .roomName, state: .state.playbackState, vol: .state.volume}' 3gr.json
```

I get this:

```
{
  "name": "Room1",
  "state": "STOPPED",
  "vol": 15
}
{
  "name": "Room2",
  "state": "STOPPED",
  "vol": 40
}
{
  "name": "Room3",
  "state": "STOPPED",
  "vol": 15
}
```

I get the same structure of the output (in these two examples the values are not important), if I process '1gr.json':

```
{
  "name": "Room1",
  "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
  "vol": 44
}
{
  "name": "Room2",
  "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
  "vol": 54
}
{
  "name": "Room3",
  "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
  "vol": 41
}
```

What I want is for the array boundaries of the group array to be preserved.  I've tried adding various combinations of `[ ]` but to no avail. So what I'd like to see is:

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "Room1",
            "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
            "vol": 44
        },
        {
            "name": "Room2",
            "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
            "vol": 54
        },
        {
            "name": "Room3",
            "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
            "vol": 41
        }
    ]
]
```

and

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "Room1",
            "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
            "vol": 44
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Room2",
            "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
            "vol": 54
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Room3",
            "state": "PAUSED_PLAYBACK",
            "vol": 41
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please follow the mcve guidelines. In particular, it would help if you could show at least one pair of input and corresponding output.

Comment: I've updated the question with two sets of input and two sets of output.

Comment: I should have written "corresponding desired output". It's not clear (to me at least) what you mean by preserving the array boundaries.

Comment: OK, I've added the output form I'd like to see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, in essence, you should be using `map` instead of `.[]`.

```
map(.members
    | map({name: .roomName, state: .state.playbackState, vol: .state.volume}) )
```

(Since `map(f)` is just `[.[]|f]`, you could also use the latter form, but writing `map` makes the intention quite clear.)